# Как точно указать 1 месяц в секундах?

Tags: php, yii2, дата, время

```
    $otDate = strtotime("2017-01-01");
    $toDate = strtotime("2017-10-01");

    for ($i = $otDate; $i <= $toDate; $i = $i + 2592000) //Цикл для считывание каждого месяца
    {
        $m = intval(date("m", $i));
        $month[] = Yii::$app->params['monthsList'][$m];

        //Получение UNIX времени, начало и конец месяца
        $m1 = $i; //начало месяца
        $m2 = $i + 2592000; //конец месяца

        //Считываем из БД кол-во уовленных
        $line_dismiss[] = History::find()->andFilterWhere([
            'AND',
            ['>=', 'date', $m1],
            ['<=', 'date', $m2],
            ['type' => 'Уволен']
        ])->count();

        //Считываем из БД кол-во принятых на работу
        $line_working[] = History::find()->andFilterWhere([
            'AND',
            ['>=', 'date', $m1],
            ['<=', 'date', $m2],
            ['type' => 'Работает']
        ])->count();

        //Считываем из БД кол-во стажеров
        $line_stazh[] = History::find()->andFilterWhere([
            'AND',
            ['>=', 'date', $m1],
            ['<=', 'date', $m2],
            ['type' => 'Стажировка']
        ])->count();
    }
```

Каждый $i показывает такие время. А мне нужно точное время. К примеру 01.01.2017, 01.02.2017 ... 
Помогите пожалуйста, буду благодарен.

01.01.2017 00:00:00 
31.01.2017 00:00:00 
02.03.2017 00:00:00 
01.04.2017 00:00:00 
01.05.2017 00:00:00 
31.05.2017 00:00:00 
30.06.2017 00:00:00 
30.07.2017 00:00:00 
29.08.2017 00:00:00 
28.09.2017 00:00:00

Comment: А вы каким календарём пользуетесь? У нас тут дремучий legacy Григорианский календарь, в одной минуте не всегда 60 секунд, что уж говорить про месяца.

Comment: http://kalkulator.pro/month-to-second.html

Comment: @Мелкий чисто из любопытства, это вы про дополнительную секунду калибровки?

Comment: В минуте не всегда 60 секунд - да, leap second.

Comment: в каждом месяце не всегда 30-ый и 31-ый день присутствует. Я сделал шаг на след. месяц статично (2592000 сек). По этой причине была моя проблема.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант, сделать так:

```
$fromDate = new DateTime("2017-01-01");
$toDate = new DateTime("2017-10-01");

while ($fromDate <= $toDate) {
    $m = intval($fromDate->format("m"));
    $month[] = Yii::$app->params['monthsList'][$m];

    //Получение UNIX времени, начало и конец месяца
    $m1 = $fromDate->getTimestamp(); //начало месяца
    $fromDate->modify("+1 month");
    $m2 = $fromDate->getTimestamp() - 1; //конец месяца
}
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое! Все отлично работает. Не знал, что есть класс DateTime.